# My bootloader works, but doesn't load my kernel into memory

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel, bootloader

I've looked more into creating my own bootloader, rather than using grub. I soon came up with this: It takes care of switching to 32bit pm, it loads my kernel from the disk & it jumps to it to execute it.

- I'm catting my kernel & my bootloader like this: `cat boot.bin kernel > img.bin`
- I'm assembling my bootloader like this: `nasm -f bin boot.s -o boot.bin`
- `i686-elf-ld -o kernel -Ttext=0x1000 kernel_entry.bin kernel.bin --oformat binary`
- I'm compiling my kernel like this: `i686-elf-gcc *.o -Ttext=0x1000 -o kernel.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -lgcc`

(`*.o` are all compiled C files which I compile like this: `i686-elf-gcc -c file.c -o file.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra`

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]

xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7c00
jmp 0:skip ; far jump

skip:
; load kernel
mov bx, 0x1000
mov dh, 17 ; reading 20 sectors should be enough ._.
mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]

call dsk_load
call load_kernel

dsk_load:
    mov [SECTORS], dh
    mov ch, 0x00 ; C = 0
    mov dh, 0x00 ; H = 0
    mov cl, 0x02 ; S = 2

    next_group:
        mov di, 5 ; retry 5 times

    again: 
        mov ah, 0x02
        mov al, [SECTORS]
        int 0x13
        jc maybe_retry
        sub [SECTORS], al ; set remaining sectors
        jz done
        mov cl, 0x01 ; read sector 1
        xor dh, 1 ; next head
        jnz next_group
        inc ch ; next cylinder
        jmp next_group

    maybe_retry:
        mov ah, 0x00 ; reset drive
        int 0x13
        dec di
        jnz again
        jmp dsk_err ; we've tried too many times, give up

    dsk_err:
        mov bx, BOOTLOADER_SIG
        call print
        mov bx, DISK_READ_FAIL
        call print
        jmp $

    done:
        ret

; print string
print:
    ; print loop
    print_loop:
        mov ah, 0x0e
        mov al, [bx] ; load current character
        cmp al, 0
        je print_return ; return when finished
        int 0x10 ; print character
        inc bx ; next character
        jmp print_loop

    print_return:
        ret

load_kernel:
    ; If all that went well, we can switch to protected mode
    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0 , eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_32_pm ; make a far jump

    [bits 32]
    init_32_pm:
        set_up_stack:
            mov esp, stack_end

        mov ax, DATA_SEG
        mov ds, ax
        mov ss, ax
        mov es, ax
        mov fs, ax
        mov gs, ax
        jmp 0x1000 ; jump to kernel_entry.s

    ; our beloved gdt
    gdt_start:
        gdt_null: ; null descriptor
            dd 0x0
            dd 0x0
        gdt_code: ; code segment descriptor
            dw 0xffff ; limit (bits 0-15)
            dw 0x0 ; base (bits 0-15)
            db 0x0 ; base (bits 16-23)
            db 10011010b ; 1st flags, type flags
            db 11001111b ; 2nd flags, Limit (bits 16-19)
            db 0x0 ; base (bits 24 - 31)
        gdt_data: ; data segment descriptor
            dw 0xffff ; limit (bits 0-15)
            dw 0x0 ; base (bits 0-15)
            db 0x0 ; base (bits 16 -23)
            db 10010010b ; 1st flags, type flags
            db 11001111b ; 2nd flags, Limit (bits 16-19)
            db 0x0 ; base (bits 24 - 31)
    gdt_end:
        gdt_descriptor:
            dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; gdt size
            dd gdt_start ; gdt start address

            ; some handy constants
            CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
            DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start

    BOOT_DRIVE db 0
    SECTORS db 0
    BOOTLOADER_SIG db "------ bootloader ------", 0x0d, 0xa, 0
    DISK_READ_FAIL db "An error occurred while loading the kernel! Please restart your computer.", 0x0d, 0xa, 0

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55

    section .bss
    stack_begin:
        resb 4096 ; 4kib stack
    stack_end:

; 9 sectors
```

The code that resides over at `0x1000` is this:

```
; kernel_entry.s

[bits 32]
[extern kmain]

call kmain
jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

; 1 sectors
```

My bootloader doesn't crash but it does not load my kernel, which should print some things to the screen.

This is the `kmain` function:

```c
void kmain(void)
{
    /* Initialize terminal */
    tty_init();
    tty_puts("Hello kernel!", VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN);
}
```

Assume the tty functions are working, since they were doing just fine when testing with grub instead of my own bootloader. Does anyone know what's going on? (Testing in bochs shows no errors)

Comment: The way you link your kernel is super strange.  Why do you have `gcc` do a link and then `ld` do a link again?

Comment: It's because of `kernel_entry`. Do you have a better way perhaps?

Comment: Just skip the `gcc`-based link and only do the link through `ld`.  You can give object files to `ld` directly.  This is actually how `ld` is meant to be used.

Comment: You have to learn (or remember) that `gcc` is only a front-end program which invokes other programs for the actual building and linking. In the case of linking it will actually invoke `ld`.

Comment: Now back to your question; unfortunately I cannot reproduce your problem as your code is not self contained.  The tty functions are missing.  Can you perhaps simplify your example such that they aren't needed?

Comment: Get rid of the tty functions. They are not really needed

Comment: @fuz it may be how ld is meant to be used, but it's not how you're meant to link programs when using gcc, so...

Comment: @user253751 In a freestanding environment, that is not correct (and in fact, rather dangerous as you don't want the hosted CRT initialisation code in your kernel).  Just take the object files produced by the compiler and pass them directly to `ld`.  Linking twice is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @fuz you shouldn't even use `gcc -ffreestanding`? What about libgcc? I believe gcc tells you to use gcc for linking, specifically because of libgcc

Comment: @user253751 Well, of course you need to manually provide libgcc in this case.  I must admit I have not studied freestanding use of gcc in detail, but whatever you do, linking twice is incorrect.